# Lie algebras with different bases

Tags: lie-algebras

I am interesting to know that if a finite dimensional Lie algebra $L$ has two bases $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, how  can we compare the cardinal of  two sets $\{(x,y)\in \beta_1\times \beta_1~|~[x,y]=0\}$ and $\{(x,y)\in \beta_2\times \beta_2~|~[x,y]=0\}$?

Thanks for any comments and suggestions.

Takjk

Comment: What a strange question...

Answer (score 0):

These cardinalities are not independent of the base, i.e., they can be quite different.
For example, consider the Heisenberg Lie algebra in the basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ with $[e_1,e_2]=e_3$. Then your cardinality is $7$ in this base, since 
$$
[e_1,e_1]=[e_2,e_2]=[e_3,e_3]=[e_1,e_3]=[e_2,e_3]=[e_3,e_1]=[e_3,e_2]=0.
$$
Only $2$ brackets in this base are nonzero, namely $[e_1,e_2]$ and $[e_2,e_1]$.
Now consider the new basis $f_1=e_1$, $f_2=e_2$ and $f_3=e_2+e_3$. In this base the cardinality is only $5$, namely
$$
[f_1,f_1]=[f_2,f_2]=[f_3,f_3]=[f_2,f_3]=[f_3,f_2]=0.
$$
Note that $[f_1,f_3]=f_3-f_2$.
For this reason one usually considers invariants in Lie theory, which are base-independent, like the dimension of the center, the annihilator, or the derived algebra.